# What is this airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, canada

Found this old pic of an aircraft that used to service the north. Was wondering if anyone could identify, or had registration information. It would have been in service sometime between 1950-1970.

[image: Northern Aircraft]

Comment: Not a complete answer but it's a Beechcraft Queen Air, which puts it 1960 the earliest.

Comment: From this link http://www.beechcraft.com/customer_support/technical_publications/docs/nontechnical/serializationList.pdf the sales year of this serial # was 1969+ (near the end of my time line). This pic must have been taken when my relative returned to the north in the mid-late 80s before it was de-registered in 1988.

Comment: Gosh -- an aircraft just for White Walkers!   :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The letters on top of the tail fin is called a [registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration) or tail number, like a license plate if you will.

In this case searching the [Canadian Civil Aircraft Register](https://wwwapps.tc.gc.ca/Saf-Sec-Sur/2/CCARCS-RIACC/RchHs.aspx) (historical search) for [C-FCGV](https://wwwapps.tc.gc.ca/Saf-Sec-Sur/2/CCARCS-RIACC/ADetHis.aspx?id=97743&rfr=RchHsRes.aspx?st=2&m=%7CFCGV%7C&cn=%7C%7C&mn=%7C%7C&sn=%7C%7C&cnn=%7C%7C&tn=%7C%7C&ln=%7C%7C&fn=%7C%7C&rfr2=RchHs.aspx) reveals that it is a [Beech model 65-B80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Queen_Air#B80) with serial number LD 408 and the owner was "Govt Canada Dept Of Transport".

> Introduced in 1966 the B80 was to be the final production model. The B80 was by far the longest produced Queen Air with production lasting some 12 years. Its major improvement was the increased gross weight to a 8,800 lb (4,000 kg). This gave the B80 a useful load of well over 3,000 lb (1,400 kg). Production ended in 1978.

It was removed from the register on 1988-02-03.

Comment: ymb1 - Thank you for the links (and thank you to all that replied). My relative flew into the arctic multiple times over the 1950-1970 time frame, but I'd never heard mention of him being on a Beech/Queen Air. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Its a [Beech Queen Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Queen_Air) (note the piston engines) the precursor to the king air.

Comment: Dave, As a novice I did not notice. Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: The main difference is that the Queen Air can move any number of squares horizontally, vertically or diagonally, whereas the King Air can only move one square at a time but has the additional safety feature that it can't be moved into the path of another plane.